# Migrating from Ubuntu to ElementaryOS

Tags: 14.04, migration, elementary

I have lots of important development files and set up in my Ubuntu installation. But now after trying Elementary OS, I'd like to make it my primary OS. Since everything in Linux is a file. I was thinking of a way to have everything in my Ubuntu migrated here.
Will copying the home folder or the `/etc` one do it?

Comment: People here wouldn't like that ;P Try http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Normally, all your personal files are included in your home folder. Therefore, it should be sufficient if you take only this folder in your new installation. Whether you've got places other files in your system that only you can answer.

System configurations you should not take into the new system. Unless you have adjusted it themselves and know what you've done.

The same for your local configurations in your home folder (dot files and folders). Create a backup and take back the things only when you really need them, step by step.